# Android XMMP Connection in Service end when app end

Tags: android, service, connection, xmpp

Currently i am facing a problem that i dont know how to solve. Basically my application connects to a XMPP chat and keeps notifying the user when a friend's status has changed. Everything working as expected. Today i advanced to the next step which is, keep sending push notifications to the user even if the application is destroyed. I have managed to keep the service running after the application ends, but for some reason, the connection to my XMPP chat ends when the application is terminated. I have no idea why and i would really apreciate some help. Here is my Service Code:

```
    package ...

    import ...

    public class ChatService extends Service {

        private final IBinder mBinder = new ChatBinder();
        public static final String F_TAG = "ChatService";
        private Context context;

        public static LoginCallBack loginCallBack;
        public static StatusChangedCallBack statusChangedCallBack;

        private String username;
        private String server;
        private String password;

        public ChatServer getChatServer() {
            return chatServer;
        }

        private ChatServer chatServer;
        private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> listDataChild;
        private ArrayList<String> listDataHeader;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            Log.i("S_TAG", "Service Binded");
            return mBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            Log.i("S_TAG", "Service Unbinded");
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Log.i("S_TAG", "Service Created");
            initListDataHeader();
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.i("S_TAG", "Service Destroyed");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(...);

            username = prefs.getString("username", null);
            password = prefs.getString("password", null);
            server = prefs.getString("server", null);

            if (username != null && password != null & server != null) {

                Log.i("T_TAG", username + password + server);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Connect to the RIOT CHAT XMPP
                        chatServer = new ChatServer(server);
                        chatServer.connect();
                        chatServer.login(username, password);

                        if (chatServer.isConnected()) { //&& chatServer.isAuthenticated()) {
                            if (chatServer.isAuthenticated()) {
                                loginCallBack.onLogin(chatServer.isAuthenticated());

                                Roster roster = chatServer.getConnection().getRoster();
                                roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {...});
                            } else {
                                // Authentication Error
                                loginCallBack.onError(1);
                            }
                        } else {
                            loginCallBack.onError(0);
                        }    
                    }
                }).start();
            } else {
                loginCallBack.onError(2);
                stopSelf();
            }
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            LogPrint.print(context, "Started Service");
        }

        public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> getListDataChild() {

           ...    
            return listDataChild;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getListDataHeader() {
            return listDataHeader;
        }

        public void initListDataHeader() {
            ...
        }

        public class ChatBinder extends Binder {
            public ChatService getService() {
                return ChatService.this;
            }
        }

        public FriendHolder findFriend(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> friends, String user) {
...
        }

        private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> swapFriends(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> listDataChild, String onlineOrOffline, int positionToRemoveUpdate) {...
        }

            private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Friend>> sendPushToActionBar (Presence p, Friend friend, Presence.Type oldPresenceType){...
        }
```

Any idea about what is causing the issue? I would like any tips that leads me to the right direction as well as tips about wrong implementation and things to improve in the code if possible. Thank you in advanced.

EDIT1: There is missing in the code the part that disables the callbacks if the application is destroyed (because there is nothing to update in the application if there is none running, just send the push notifications), but for now i just want to understand why the connection ends.

EDIT2: I am using **a**Smack, i could upload the code but i honestly think the problem is somewhere here in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution, although forgot to close the case. The provided code is working as intended, I was just missing an exception that was being happening and it made the service restart itself and thus, lose the connection.